# Where does "0 packages can be updated." come from?

Tags: command-line, login

Where does `0 packages can be updated.` come from in the login process?

Answer (score 22):

These messages come from `update-motd`.

The `/etc/update-motd.d/updates-available` script generates this specific output from `cat /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available`

Answer (score 2):

In answer to where do all of the MOTD messages come from, first look at the PAM configs.

```
 % grep -C1 motd /etc/pam.d/*
 /etc/pam.d/sshd:session optional pam_motd.so motd=/run/motd.dynamic
```

Look to see what pam_motd.so runs.

```
 % strings /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_motd.so
 run-parts /etc/update-motd.d > /run/motd.dynamic.new
```

'run-parts' runs all the scripts, in order, in a directory.

```
 % ls /etc/update-motd.d/
 00-header*     80-esm*  91-release-upgrade*  98-reboot-required*
 10-help-text*  80-livepatch*          95-hwe-eol*
 50-motd-news*  90-updates-available*  98-fsck-at-reboot*
```

Helper scripts are in /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd*

```
 /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot*
 /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-hwe-eol*
 /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-reboot-required*
 /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available*
```

Data files are in /var/lib/update-notifier

```
 dpkg-run-stamp  hwe-eol                  updates-available
 fsck-at-reboot  package-data-downloads/  user.d/
```

To output the MOTD info from the command line, either

```
$ ssh localhost
```

or

```
# run-parts /etc/update-motd.d
```